# Could somebody explain me what is the difference of msg.sender, spender, from, to, owner in ERC20?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I read ERC20 solidity code below.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

Then, I couldn't understand what the terms of msg.sender, spender, from, to, owner  mean.

I guessed msg.sender equals from, spender equals to, and msg.sender equals owner.
But if this hypothesis is true, allowed[from][msg.sender] isn't well defined.

I searched deeply but I couldn't get any information mentioned about above.
Could anyone describe the definition and usage?

Answer (score 5):

`msg.sender` is always the account that called the function. So any time you're reading code and see `msg.sender`, think "caller."

The caller is logically different entities depending on what function you're looking at. In the constructor, `msg.sender` is the account creating the contract (the "owner"). In a call to `transfer`, the caller is the owner of the coins being transferred,  etc.

- In `transfer(to, amount)`, tokens are transferred from `msg.sender` to `to`.
- In `transferFrom(from, to, amount)`, `msg.sender` is the "spender" of tokens that are being transferred from `from` to `to`.
- In `allow(spender, amount)`, `msg.sender` is authorizing `spender` to be able to call `transferFrom` later.
- In `allowed[from][msg.sender]`, we're checking how many tokens `from` has previously allowed `msg.sender` to spend.

Comment: How about factory pattern, like a contract call function in another contract?

Comment: @HoangMinhDung you should see the difference between `tx.origin` and `msg.sender`, which is out of scope for this question